# I didn't check the Targeted for iPad option when creating a View Controller. How can I fix my UIView to be targeted for iPad devices using XCode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I made a mistake when I created one of my `UIViewController` objects.  When I created the files, I forgot to select the *Target for iPad* option.

[image: 'Targeted for iPad' not selected]

I never considered this to be much of an issue, because I always change my initial view within the generated Nib file to not display a statusbar, and to be freeform in sizing.

However, I've recently ran into a problem.  The `UIViewController` that I created that wasn't *Targeted for iPad* has a toolbar on it.  This means that the default style is a bluish color.  The problem is that all of my other views were created for the iPad and the default iPad style is a greyish tone, instead of the bluish tint color that is associated with iPhone/iPod devices.

I need my application to remain consistent and I'd rather not start from scratch, re-making my Nib file, and re-wiring it to my `ViewController.h` file.

How can I fix my Nib and View Controller so that it behaves as if it is *Targeted for iPad*, even though I've mistakenly not specified it as such?

Comment: You could create a new *Targeted for iPad* nib and cut-and-paste the contents from the old one.  I think you'll still need to rewire it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this at your own risk:

First, back-up your original Xib file.  Next, modify the second line from:

`<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="8.00">`

to

`<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB" version="8.00">`

Next, open the source code of the xib, and in every ocurrence of the element:

```
<string key="IBDocument.TargetRuntimeIdentifier">
```

Replace the value `IBCocoaTouchFramework` with `IBIPadFramework`.

Good luck!

Comment: Also, maybe you should have to modified the line 2 with <archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB" version="8.00">

Comment: Luis, I'm not sure if you yet have the privileges to update your answer, so I integrated your last comment into youe answer.  This is what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change it in Build Settings -> Targeted device family OR under Devices in Summary tab.

You'll find the above in your project's Targets section.

EDIT: Sorry for the misunderstanding. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488280/converting-iphone-xib-to-ipad-xib) SO post seems to address your issue.

Comment: No, this answer is for the project.  The project is set to be target strictly for the iPad.  However, one single UIViewController+Nib was not created with that option checked.  How can I fix the Nib?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the update.  I slightly modified my title.  Your linked question is answered, however, it's not the one that's marked the answer.  My question is in regards ti XCode 4.2+.  I think this is going to have to be done through modifying the XML in the Xib. :(